# Salesforce.com Integration with JD Edwards

Tags: webservices, integration

Looking for solution approach to integrate Salesforce.com with [JD Edwards](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/jd-edwards-enterpriseone/overview/index.html) (JDE).

Just learnt that using typical web services we cannot integrate as JDE has limitation to send data to middleware only in xml format. Without middleware it will send data in EDI or text format only. So we cannot integrate directly using web services.

Looking for options without any middleware if possible, anyone have done SFDC integration with JDE without middleware?
if not possible without the middleware any specific / cost effective middleware suggestions appreciated.

Comment: WebServices communicate by XML so that should not have to be a problem..    How are the XML's sent by JDE?

Comment: I suggest you [Write out both the full version and the abbreviation at first occurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Write_out_both_the_full_version_and_the_abbreviation_at_first_occurrence). And make one or the other a link to a relevant posting about the product/technology. I for one have no idea what JDE is.

Comment: @guy JDE sends xml only to the middlewares and not to other systems directly as per internal JDE consultants.

Comment: You can set up an Apex REST Method to accept text data over an HTTP connection. What is the text format - do you have a link to the syntax?

Comment: @metadaddy  - this is the text format I received from JDE.                          Sl.no Name Date City 1 Testfile 25.10.2014 Hyderabad.

Comment: @metadaddy Just a thought - will lightening connect and open data protocol will support JDE Integration?

Comment: Depends on whether JD Edwards supports OData. You'd need to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach here would be to implement an [Apex REST Method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_rest_methods.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_rest_methods.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) but, instead of having the platform parse a JSON or XML payload, read the text data from the RestRequest body and parse it in Apex. A simple implementation that works with your example data:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/jde_integration')
global class JdeIntegration {
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {
        String req = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        System.debug('Req: '+req);

        // Data in format 'Sl.no Name Date City 1 Testfile 25.10.2014 Hyderabad'
        // Want to split on whitespace, at most 8 substrings (city might have spaces)
        String[] params = req.split('\\s', 8);

        String name = params[5];
        String datt = params[6]; // date is a reserved word!
        String city = params[7];

        System.debug('Got name: '+name+', date: '+datt+', city:'+city);

        // Now you can insert a record, or do whatever you need to
    }
}
```

Testing with curl. Note, you need to specify the content type:

```
$ curl -v -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-d 'Sl.no Name Date City 1 Testfile 25.10.2014 Hyderabad' \
https://na1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/jde_integration
```

Log output:

```
09:14:41.127 (127782275)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|Req: Sl.no Name Date City 1 Testfile 25.10.2014 Hyderabad
09:14:41.139 (139188394)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|Got name: Testfile, date: 25.10.2014, city:Hyderabad
```

The sample handles a single record. If JD Edwards is sending multiple records (presumably separated by newlines), you'll need to modify it accordingly.